# User script or extension to avoid remote resources: fonts, scripts etc. [Chromium and recent Firefox browsers]

Tags: web-browser

Many a website refers to specific centralized remote resources. I.e. resources not hosted from the domain (or subdomains) of said website. Examples of this are Google fonts served from Google servers (mostly `gstatic.com`). And Bootstrap-based websites (`bootstrapcdn.com`) seem to be further offenders in that regard.

Are there any user scripts (TamperMonkey and friends) or extensions that allow me to substitute such remote fonts with locally cached/stored ones or even redirect to a proxy that I set up? The browsers I use mostly are Chromium-based browsers and the most recent Firefox versions.

The reason I want this is because of the privacy implications of using those remote resources from centralized services and because many websites look bad if one simply *blocks* remote fonts, for example. And yes, I realize that `gstatic.com` is cookie-less, but that doesn't mean that they don't get all kinds of fascinating and "useful" (for them, not me) metadata I'd rather not want them to have.

---

uBlock Origin and uMatrix allow me to assume control over what I want to block or allow, but they don't provide a remedy for remote fonts (or scripts).

Comment: Just to stress: while uBlock Origin does *block* such resources, it does not *substitute a replacement* (i.e. what's blocked won't work). A partial solution would be DecentralEyes, which substitutes *some* (but not all) resources. As it (unless I missed that in its configuration) e.g. doesn't substitute fonts, I just leave it as comment here (might be a partial solution until someone comes up with a real one; please ping me then, I'd be very interested in that, too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Decentraleyes](https://decentraleyes.org/):

- Loads most popular CDN files locally (no remote requests are made for jQuery, Bootstrap, etc.)
- Can block requests for any missing CDN resources (i.e. JS, CSS, Font files)

> Websites have increasingly begun to rely much more on large third-parties for content delivery. Canceling requests for ads or trackers is usually without issue, however blocking actual content, not unexpectedly, breaks pages. The aim of this add-on is to cut-out the middleman by providing lightning speed delivery of local (bundled) files to improve online privacy.
>
> • Protects privacy by evading large delivery networks that claim to offer free services.
>   • Complements regular blockers such as uBlock Origin (recommended), Adblock Plus, et al.
>   • Works directly out of the box; absolutely no prior configuration required.

Download for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/decentraleyes/), and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/decentraleyes/ldpochfccmkkmhdbclfhpagapcfdljkj)